# Append multiple value in Dictionary values with same key

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I want to append multiple values with same key in dictionary.

```
mydict={'dd6729': np.array([-0.06136101]),
        '941a60': np.array([-0.03989978])}
```

Desired Output:

```
{'dd6729': [array([-0.06136101]),array([-0.06136101])], '941a60': [array([-0.03989978]),array([-0.06136101])]}
```

I tried something like this :

```
for i,v in mydict.items():
    mydict[i].append(v)
print(mydict)
```

but got error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-398-fbc8d90525de> in <module>
      1 for i,v in mydict.items():
----> 2     mydict[i].append(v)
      3 print(mydict)
      4 

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

As the values are Numpy array so I am unable to append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use defaultdict of this problem

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict={'dd6729': np.array([-0.06136101]),
    '941a60': np.array([-0.03989978])}
new_dict=defaultdict(list)
for i,v in mydict.items():
    new_dict[i].append(v)
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: After adding :  " <<<for i,v in new_dict.items():
                           new_dict[i].append(v[0]) >>> "   I got perfect result.

Answer (score 2):

Your values in the dictionary are not consistent for different keys, and you may end up running into a problem later. Why don't you define it as a list in the first place? like this:

```
mydict={'dd6729': [np.array([-0.06136101])],
        '941a60': [np.array([-0.03989978])]}
```

Then later on, if you have any further processing on the values, it would be much easier to read and process the values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mydict[i]` is a `numpy.ndarray` so to append to it you either need to use the `numpy.append` function, or use a regular list instead.

```python
for i,v in mydict.items():
    mydict[i] = np.append(mydict[i], v)
print(mydict)
```

P.S.
I don't know if that's what  you meant but the output becomes:

```python
{'dd6729': array([-0.06136101, -0.06136101]), '941a60': array([-0.03989978, -0.03989978])}
```

instead of your desired output (the second item in `'941a60'`).

Comment: I want to add like this [array([-0.06136101]),array([-0.06136101])] not like this array([-0.06136101, -0.06136101]) .. I want to add two different array/values in a list with same key .your answer add another value in same array.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Python list and replace the old value:

```
mydict={'dd6729': np.array([-0.06136101]),
        '941a60': np.array([-0.03989978])}

for i,v in mydict.items():
    mydict[i] = [v, v]

print(mydict)
```

Out:

```
{'dd6729': [array([-0.06136101]), array([-0.06136101])], '941a60': [array([-0.03989978]), array([-0.03989978])]}
```

Comment: I want to add like this [array([-0.06136101]),array([-0.06136101])] not like this array([-0.06136101, -0.06136101]) .. I want to add two different array/values in a list with same key .your answer add another value in same array.

Comment: @Sweety Tripathi: Edited.

Answer (score 0):

In mydict[i].append(v), mydict[i] is a numpy array which doesn't have a attribute append.

If want to append to the numpy array, you can use np.append.
i.e.

```
    for i,v in mydict.items():
        mydict[i] = np.append(mydict[i], v)
```

Comment: I want to add two different array/values in a list with same key .your answer add another value in same array.

Answer (score 0):

After converting dictionary values to list and then append another array value to it gives desired output.

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict={'dd6729': np.array([-0.06136101]),
    '941a60': np.array([-0.03989978])}

new_dict=defaultdict(list)

for i,v in mydict.items():
    new_dict[i].append(v)

for i,v in new_dict.items():
    new_dict[i].append(v[0])
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'dd6729': [array([-0.06136101]), array([-0.06136101])],
             '941a60': [array([-0.03989978]), array([-0.03989978])]})
```